# Valgrind invalid read errors even though there's no memory leak

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

So I have somehing like this in "main.c"

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct myStruct
{
    int dummyMember1;
    float dummyMember2;
} myStruct_t;

int main()
{
    myStruct_t* a = malloc(sizeof(myStruct_t));
    a->dummyMember1 = 10;
    a->dummyMember2 = 5.5;
    push(a);

    myStruct_t* b = pop();
    if(b != NULL)
    {
        b->dummyMember1;
        b->dummyMember2;
    }

    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

And then I have something like this in some file "foo.h"

```
void push(void* item);
void* pop();
```

And in the "foo.c" I have something like this

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 50

void* arr[ARR_SIZE];

int free_space = ARR_SIZE;

void push(void* item)
{
    if(free_space > 0){
        arr[ARR_SIZE - free_space] = item;
        free_space--;
    }
    return;
}

void* pop()
{
    void* p_ret = NULL;
    if(free_space < ARR_SIZE)
    {
        void* p = arr[ARR_SIZE-(free_space+1)];
        p_ret = malloc(sizeof(*p));
        memcpy(p_ret, p, sizeof(*p));
        free(p);
        free_space++;
    }
    return p_ret;
}
```

This code compiles and run without segfaults but the problem is valgrind is reporting invalid read errors (even though it says "All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible").

My question is, what's causing valgrind to report the invalid read errors (which is all referring to the pop() function)?

Comment: Don't add tags for unrelated languages. C++ is not C is not C++!

Comment: The **exact** errors, relative to the **exact** code, are not only pertinent to your problem, they're pretty-much mandatory in determining exactly what the issue is. Choosing not to post either isn't helpful in solving the problem. I am, however, curious to know what the relationship is between `buff` and `arr`. LIkewise with what you think `sizeof(*p)` is when `p` is `void*`.

Comment: `void* p = buff[ARR_SIZE-(free_space+1)]; free(p);`. What is `buff`? Is it really an array of dynamically allocated pointers? Instead of posting "something like that" code please post the exact code as a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `void* p =...; ... malloc(sizeof(*p));` is invalid. Size of `void` is not defined.

Comment: ok I'm going to edit this code

Comment: @kaylum sorry that was a typo. I originally decided to use buff but then change it to arr which is the more general form

Comment: @YandereLolicon165 you must post the actual code that reported the errors. Don't decide to change stuff while copying it over to here

Comment: @M.M I know I'm recreating the minimal complete and verifiable example as suggested by kaylum

Comment: Consider deleting this question while you sort out what you want to post.  Then undelete it when it is ready after all.

Comment: GCC has a nasty habit of allowing you to abuse `void *` as if it was `char *`.  I think you're running foul of that permissiveness.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm done editing actually. Now there is it a working minimal code

Comment: Thanks.  I get `main.c:21:9: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
         b->dummyMember1;` and
  
`main.c:22:9: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
         b->dummyMember2;`
when I compile with my default compilation options.  Presumably, printing the values would be OK?

Comment: that's because u treat the warning as errors.

Comment: Well, of course.  I've only been coding in C for thirty years so I can't afford to ignore compiler warnings.  If it's any consolation, `valgrind` is wittering; I'm about to try and work out why.  One set of warnings is: `==59504== Invalid read of size 4`
`==59504==    at 0x100000EBF: main (main.c:21)`
`==59504==  Address 0x100aa74e4 is 3 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd`
`==59504==    at 0x100007E81: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)`
`==59504==    by 0x100000E50: pop (foo.c:26)`
`==59504==    by 0x100000EA4: main (main.c:18)`.  Note that 'block of size 1' — that's GCC messing you around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in `push()` and `pop()` is a tad convoluted.  Taking your code and making minimal necessary changes to compile under my preferred compiler options, and then running it under `valgrind`, I get the warning:

```
==59504== Invalid read of size 4
==59504==    at 0x100000EBF: main (main.c:21)
==59504==  Address 0x100aa74e4 is 3 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==59504==    at 0x100007E81: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==59504==    by 0x100000E50: pop (foo.c:26)
==59504==    by 0x100000EA4: main (main.c:18)
```

The trouble is in your `pop()` function; you are trying to allocate `sizeof(*p)` bytes where `p` is a `void *`, so `*p` is a `void`, which doesn't have a size.  GCC (unhelpfully in my opinion) treats that as a request for `1` byte, rather than give the error that should be given.  You have to request `-pedantic` warnings to get the message:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror -pedantic -c foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘pop’:
foo.c:26:30: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a void type [-Werror=pointer-arith]
         p_ret = malloc(sizeof(*p));
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:186:0,
                 from foo.c:3:
foo.c:27:32: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a void type [-Werror=pointer-arith]
         memcpy(p_ret, p, sizeof(*p));
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

Since you are storing `void *` values in a fixed array, you don't need any dynamic memory allocation in the stack.  You could use:

```
#include "foo.h"

enum { ARR_SIZE = 50 };

static void *arr[ARR_SIZE];
static int   free_space = ARR_SIZE;

void push(void *item)
{
    if (free_space > 0)
    {
        arr[ARR_SIZE - free_space] = item;
        free_space--;
    }
}

void *pop(void)
{
    void *p_ret = 0;
    if (free_space < ARR_SIZE)
    {
        p_ret = arr[ARR_SIZE - (free_space + 1)];
        free_space++;
    }
    return p_ret;
}
```

With a revised test program:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct myStruct
{
    int dummyMember1;
    float dummyMember2;
} myStruct_t;

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        myStruct_t *a = malloc(sizeof(myStruct_t));
        a->dummyMember1 = 10 + i;
        a->dummyMember2 = 5.5 * i;
        push(a);

        myStruct_t *b = pop();
        if (b != NULL)
        {
            printf("Popped: %d and %f\n", b->dummyMember1, b->dummyMember2);
        }

        free(a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get `valgrind` output such as:

```
==59611== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==59611== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==59611== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==59611== Command: foo
==59611== 
--59611-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "./foo"
Popped: 10 and 0.000000
Popped: 11 and 5.500000
Popped: 12 and 11.000000
==59611== 
==59611== HEAP SUMMARY:
==59611==     in use at exit: 26,437 bytes in 189 blocks
==59611==   total heap usage: 274 allocs, 85 frees, 32,661 bytes allocated
==59611== 
==59611== LEAK SUMMARY:
==59611==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==59611==    indirectly lost: 68 bytes in 2 blocks
==59611==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==59611==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==59611==         suppressed: 26,289 bytes in 186 blocks
==59611== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==59611== 
==59611== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==59611== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

That looks bad — there's lost memory.  But running with `--leak-check=full` yields:

```
==59641== 148 (80 direct, 68 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 43 of 66
==59641==    at 0x100007E81: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==59641==    by 0x1001E58D6: __Balloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==59641==    by 0x1001E2553: __rv_alloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==59641==    by 0x1001E2574: __nrv_alloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==59641==    by 0x10020B3E6: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==59641==    by 0x1002346C8: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==59641==    by 0x10020A389: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==59641==    by 0x100208223: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==59641==    by 0x100000EA4: main (main.c:23)
```

I tried adding `fclose(stdout)`, but that didn't fix it.  The problem is buried deep inside the local `printf()` function, and is completely outside both your control and mine.  I need to add a suppression.  Mac OS X tends to have quite a lot of these sorts of leaks — witness the suppressions already in situ (almost 27 KiB in 180+ allocations).

---

If you really must use memory allocation in your stack, you need to think rather carefully about what you're pushing onto the stack, and what you're popping off it.  You may need to know the size of the objects you're storing.  Then you'd demonstrate that the stack isn't affected by modifying the value pushed onto the stack because the stack copied the value.  While you're just stacking pointers, you only need dynamic memory allocation if the stack grows when the current array is too small.

Answer (score 0):

just care about compile instead of result.two places may be wrong.
the first one:

```
myStruct_t* structVar = pop();
//it can not realize structVar like this,you must use 'force converse'.
myStruct_t* structVar = (myStruct_t *)pop();
```

the second one:

```
p_ret = malloc(sizeof(*p));
//sizeof() parameters must be Object ,data type,and size.
p_ret = malloc(sizeof(p));
memcpy(p_ret, p, sizeof(p));
```

hope helpful to you.

Comment: the second one kinda solved it